# How to create a new column in a select query with the column validation result?

Tags: sql

I have a table with ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC and I wanted to have a NewColumn with some validation. If all the ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC have a value as "Yes" then NewColumn also should show "Yes" otherwise "No".

Basically, I want to do some validation on the existing Columns and store the result in the NewColumn. Is it possible? Someone can please help here? Thank you!

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| No | Yes | No | ColumnA & ColumnC has No |
| Yes | Yes | No | ColumnC has No |
| Yes | No | No | ColumnB & ColumnC has No |

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to only get answers that work for you. Does your DBMS feature `CONCAT_WS`? That could be useful here.

Comment: And you should not change requests. You asked for YES/NO and got an answer. You should accept this and make a new request with your new question. Or solve this yourself. There are six possible combinations that you can easily put in a `CASE` expression to get the desired result strings. Look up `CASE` in your DBMS's docs to see how to have multiple conditions.

Comment: And are you really storing 'Yes' and 'No' strings? Doesn't your DBMS support boolean columns (where the value would be true or false)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `case` with three conditions:

```sql
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,
  case when ColumnA = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnB = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnC = 'Yes'
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end NewColumn
from my_table
```

Update:

To get names of columns you'll need to concatenate names of those columns, and then remove `&`  at the end. How you can do it depends on DBMS. For example in Oracle or Postgre it could be done this way:

```sql
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,
  case when ColumnA = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnB = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnC = 'Yes'
       then 'Yes'
       else (
            REGEXP_REPLACE(case when ColumnA = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnA & ' end ||
            case when ColumnB = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnB & ' end ||
            case when ColumnC = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnC & ' end,'..$','') || 'has No'
       )
  end NewColumn
from my_table
```

In MySQL it would be

```sql
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,
  case when ColumnA = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnB = 'Yes' and 
            ColumnC = 'Yes'
       then 'Yes'
       else (
            CONCAT(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(case when ColumnA = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnA & ' end,
                    case when ColumnB = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnB & ' end,
                    case when ColumnC = 'Yes' then '' else 'ColumnC & ' end),'..$',''), 
                'has No')
       )
  end NewColumn
from my_table
```

Comment: Thanks Mark this resolved for row 1. Is there a way we can get which column validation results in NewColumn. For the row #2 is it possible to get "ColumnA & ColumnC have No" in NewColumn. For the row #3 is it possible to get "ColumnC have No" in NewColumn. For the row #4 is it possible to get "ColumnB & ColumnC have No" in NewColumn.

Comment: @sprajendra, please edit the question and show desired outcome there.

Comment: Hi Mark, Is it possible to print Column names in NewColumn when Column value is No.

Comment: @sprajendra, Yes it is possible. Edit question, replace values in last column of your example with what exactly you want to get, and I will provide you the query for that.

Comment: Hi Mark, Update the table with the expected info. Could you please let me know? Thanks